# Best course to learn Adobe Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, education

I am a rookie at Adobe Photoshop and Adobe Illustrator and I just want to know the best courses I can find on the internet to learn.

I've been looking for courses a lot and all good I find is either only essentials for latest versions or complete courses for old versions.

I just need a guide from you experts on where should I look for.

These could either be paid or free. I just need good learning options.

After that, if you have any specific guidelines on where to move forward with that if I want to learn Logo Design, Stationary Design, Brochure Design or Website Design.

Thank you very much

Comment: Generally you do not go ahead and learn Photoshop. You go ahead and learn a skill that you use Photoshop for. There are quite infinite uses for the software. And you wouldn't use Photoshop for logo design, most likely not stationary design and brochure design. And you would try to avoid it for website design.

Comment: @joojaa This would have been a great (if not the best) answer, why comment it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the most thorough learning resource *without* taking formal classes... the **Adobe Classroom in a Book** series will teach you *everything* in any application they produce.

It's dry, not very entertaining, will take you forever to get through, but is a complete course on every tool and feature. So, Pick up a copy of **Adobe Photoshop Classroom in a Book."

Of course, learning the tool is only one part. Practice is the other.

Answer (score 1):

I have always found [Lynda.com](https://www.lynda.com/) one of the best resources for learning - starts at about $250 pa in my country - you can browse most of the resources selected chapters - to see if its for you *before you buy*, some of the videos are on YouTube.

Both my wife and daughter have free ed-accounts because they are in FT education and I can login as them if needed - for the quality of material the spend is pretty reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop shines when one wants to edit photos, paint or make combinatons of the forementioned. Texts, vector shapes and 3D are all useful extras but not the areas where Photoshop is the most obvious choice of a professional. Those capablities in Photoshop are useful because one can do his work in one program, and even with a good collection of tools if the most part of it contains bitmap graphics.

You have declared some especially interesting uses. Those are higher level goals than using Photoshop. User @joojaa has in his comment written that out already very clearly. Photoshop is poor tool to handle those goals. It's good only for making and editing the images for those goals.

Illustrator is the same except it's made for vector graphics. It can also handle very well the making of single page printings.

You can well take some learning material for previous versions. The skills which that naterial teach are still essential and valid.

A thousand learned tricks are nothing if you cannot solve practical problems. Most important is to develop your abilities to think the ways how to achieve something wanted. Nobody pays for mixing colors or drawing curves - no matter, how well it's done. They want a file that can be printed, published or imported to a bigger job. That file must contain a work where you have inputted something using some creativity and effort that they haven't or they are too busy.

You can well train yourself in it by making something existing better or presenting the same things differently. A faceless "do it yourself course cannot" help you in this, you need some personal feedback, too. So find a teacher who can give some crituque and guidance in greater lines. The tricks can be learned from tutorials.

Comment: So you're saying there isn't anything I can do to learn from home? I sort of donot have an option for a course because I can't find any in my city. Is there any way possible I could move forward with this? How about this: https://teamtreehouse.com/library/topic:design

Comment: @FahadSohail If you have a computer, the graphics software and working internet comnnection, all learning is possible at home. (=work tutorials, check, what others have done and try to do it better or other way and contact to somewhere to get quidance - the last is better locally if possible. A web school is a good option, too, if it's available. Run the trial. Do it offer feedback? I cannot advertise paid services here.